# Why it is important to Securing /dev/shm and /tmp

Tags: security

I see a lot of blogs talking about security and specially how to secure **/dev/shm** and **/tmp**

I would like to know why it is important to secure these folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/tmp` and `/var/tmp` are *supposed* to be world-writable (and [sticky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit)) so that all programs and/or users can create their temporary files there. 
[From TLDP](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Security-HOWTO/file-security.html):

> World-writable files, particularly system files, can be a security hole if a cracker gains access to your system and modifies them. Additionally, world-writable directories are dangerous, since they allow a cracker to add or delete files as he wishes. To locate all world-writable files on your system, use the following command:

```
sudo find / -perm -2 ! -type l -ls
```

> and be sure you know why those files are writable. In the normal course of operation, several files will be world-writable, including some from /dev, and symbolic links, thus the ! -type l which excludes these from the previous find command.